# Is it possible to tunnel PPTP over SSH?

Tags: networking, vpn, tunnel, pptp

I'm trying to get my iDevice to use its USB connection for all network access, instead of WiFi. I had thought it would be as simple as using a VPN, and routing that VPN through some ports I'm forwarding from the iDevice, but that's not quite working.

Have I misconfigured something, or is it simply not possible to tunnel PPTP over SSH?

I've forwarded ports 1723 and 47 (using ssh -R) from the device to the PPTP server and configured the client to connect to localhost. However, it fails to connect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SSH tunnels TCP.  AFAIK it is not possible to ssh tunnel GRE.

The 47 is the IP [protocol number](http://www.iana.org/assignments/protocol-numbers/protocol-numbers.xhtml) for GRE.  It is not a port number.  GRE is a protocol at the same layer as TCP or UDP.  GRE is directly above IP.